# String of 10 randomly chosen digits -- probability question

Tags: probability

Given a string of 10 randomly and independently chosen digits from 1-9.  Let N be the number of digits missing from the sequence.  Calculate expectation and variance of N.

Comment: is it homework?

Comment: Can the digits from 1-9 be repeated.  Is it from 0-9 or 1-9.  If it is 0-9, there are 10 numbers to select from and if it is 1-9, there are 9 numbers to select from.  Further can the string be 1 digit  to 9 digit.  The question is not all that clear.  Could you add a little bit of more color?

Comment: This is a string of exactly 10 digits and 0 is not included so only digits 1-9.  The digits can be repeated without limit and can appear in any order.  The selection of the digits is random and independent.  N is a random variable representing the number of digits not appearing in the string (so if 2 and 4 do not appear in a certain string N=2).  Must find mean and variance of N.

Answer (score 1):

**Outline:** Define random variable $X_i$ by $X_i=1$ if digit $i$ is missing, and $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then the number $N$ of digits missing is given by
$$N=X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_9.$$ 
By the linearity of expectation, we have 
$$E(X_1+\cdots +X_9)=E(X_1)+\cdots +E(X_9).$$
For each $i$, the probability $i$ is missing is $\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^{10}$.  Thus the expected number missing is $9\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^{10}$.

For the variance, note that if $N$ is the number of digits missing, then 
$$\text{Var}(N)=E(N^2)-(E(N))^2.$$

So we will be finished if we can find $E(N^2)$. By linearity, this is the sum of the $E(X_i^2)$, plus the sum of the $E(X_iX_j)$, as $(i,j)$ runs over all pairs with $i\ne j$.

The $E(X_i^2)$ are easy, since $X_i^2=X_i$.

For $XiX_j$ with $i\ne j$, we have $X_iX_j=1$ unless $i$ and $j$ $i$ are both missing. So $\Pr(X_iX_j=1)=\left(\frac{7}{9}\right)^{10}$.

Now put the pieces together.

Comment: $X_i X_j = 1$ only if both $i$ and $j$ are present. The final probability calculation is incorrect.

Comment: $X_iX_j=0$ unless $i$ and $j$ are both missing.

Comment: Can't you just use the fact that each Xi is a Bernoulli and for the variance do p(1-p)?  Then add them up because they are independent so there are no covariance terms?